Hi, i tried everything i know but no use, convert and calculate
Convert PurchaseDate to datetime type with specified format:
data['PurchaseDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data['PurchaseDate']) # dtype is: datetime64

Now calculating which spouse to go well:
# Calculate Recency
data['Recency'] = (datetime.now().date() - data['PurchaseDate'].dt.date).dt.days

output:
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

I tried coerce, format='%Y-%m-%d', parse date, nothing worked.
I want to calculate Recency, Frequency and Monetary value, the Recency kept on returning the same error mentioned above.

Thank you, Mr. Hamid for the editing, appreciate your help

Can you try this ?
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data['PurchaseDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data['PurchaseDate'], format='%d-%b-%y')

# Calculate Recency
data['Recency'] = (datetime.now().date() - data['PurchaseDate']).dt.days


The issue is the subtraction operator. Given the error, it appears that the subtraction operation between the current date and the 'PurchaseDate' column is still resulting in an unsupported operand type.

the conversion went fine'# Convert 'PurchaseDate' column to datetime
data['PurchaseDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data['PurchaseDate'], format='%Y-%m-%d')'. calculations is the issue '# Calculate Recency
data['Recency'] = (datetime.now().date() - data['PurchaseDate']).dt.days',

i tired '# Calculate Recency
data['Recency'] = (datetime.now().date() - data['PurchaseDate']).dt.days', '# Calculate Recency
data['Recency'] = (datetime.now().date() - pd.to_datetime(data['PurchaseDate'])).dt.days,. same error. the conversion output: datetime64[ns]
